# Laravel - React , Forcing Axios for reject/catch

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I have a `Laravel` API which sends the current user either a JSON `UserObject`(if Logged on) or `None`/blank result(if no current User).

The frontend is React with axios to get data from API.

```
        Axios.get('/api/user/current')
        .then((response) => {
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            alert('Login Failed '+ error);
        });
```

since `Axios` is a promise, it will either resolve or reject.

If I send a blank value in API, it will still consider as resolve.
How can I force the `axios` to reject if there is no current user in API.

I can have `if`..`else` in the response callback to distingush between a user and a guest, but I just wanna know if its possible to force a catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either respond with a 204 status if you dont want to send any data back. Or even better a 404 if that particular resource doesnt exist.

The 404 will be considered a rejection by axios.

Answer (score 0):

you can use axios [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to modify the request and responses.